# Javascript adding to an interval of an array

Tags: javascript

Let's say that I have an array `var x = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, and I would like to add 1 to the second and the third element of the array. In Python numpy I could do `x[1:3] += 1` to add to the interval from 1st to 3rd (3rd excluded) element of x. Is there a similar method in JavaScript?

Comment: So `1` would be the second and `3` the third element?

Comment: there is no such method is JavaScript. You can try mapping over the array if you want to avoid traditional for loop

Comment: No. You need to use a `for` loop.

Comment: You can try this `x = x.map((v, i) => (i >= 1 && i < 3 ? v + 1 : v));`

Comment: `[2, 3].forEach((v) => (x[v - 1] += 1));` where [2,3] are second and third element from given array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a function with a closure

```js
const
    map = (start, end, fn) => (v, i) => i >= start && i <= end ? fn(v) : v,
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = x.map(map(1, 2, v => v + 1));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to beat python on this, but how about golang? Here's a quick POC:

```js
function _toInt(s, def = null) {
    try {
        let n = Number(s);
        return Number.isInteger(n) ? n : def;
    } catch {
        return def;
    }
}

class _Slice {
    constructor(ary, idx) {
        this.ary = ary;
        let ii = idx.split(':');
        this.start = _toInt(ii[0], 0);
        this.end = _toInt(ii[1], ary.length);
        this.step = _toInt(ii[2], 1);
    }

    get(obj, p) {
        let n = _toInt(p);
        if (n === null)
            return this[p];
        let k = this.start + n * this.step;
        return this.ary[k];
    }

    set(obj, p, val) {
        let n = _toInt(p);
        if (n === null)
            return this[p] = val;
        let k = this.start + n * this.step;
        return this.ary[k] = val;
    }

    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let i = 0, k = this.start; k < this.end; k += this.step, i++) {
            yield [i, this.ary[k]]
        }
    }
}

let Slice = (ary, idx) => new Proxy([], new _Slice(ary, idx));

//

let array = [0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]

let slice = Slice(array, '1:8:2')

for (let [i, _] of slice)
    slice[i] *= 100;

console.log(array)
```

With some more love, this should allow us to do

```
Slice([1,2,3,4,5,6])['1::4'] = 9 // [1,9,9,9,5,6] 
Slice([1,2,3,4,5,6])['1::4'] = [7, 8, 9] // [1,7,8,9,5,6]
```

and of course

```
Slice([1,2,3,4,5,6])['::-1'] // [6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: ... what is love ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz: indeed ))))